# How do i mock "chrome.storage" API for testing?

Tags: node.js, browser, mocking

How do I mock ["chrome.storage"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) (local/session) API for the testing in node.js environment? To be more detailed i'd prefer to have any implementation that actually works in node.js, probably some in-memory implementation?

I've found some mock like [this](https://github.com/acvetkov/sinon-chrome), but it's just no-op implementation and i actually need to be able to get a result with according "get" call after a "set" call.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using [mem-storage-area](https://github.com/tableflip/mem-storage-area) package.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple mock function that uses the LocalStorage and works with `get()` `set()` `remove()` `clear()`

[Chrome.Storage---Mock-API](https://github.com/txxxc/Chrome.Storage---Mock-API/blob/main/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

This is using `vitest`. The same should be possible with any other mocking frameworks. The `setUserId` and `getUserId` are the actual methods that uses chrome storage API

```
{
   it('stores the user id', async () => {
    
    global.chrome = {};
    
    chrome['storage'] = {
        local: {
            set: async (kvp) => {throw new Error('Unimplemented')},
            get: async (key) => {throw new Error('Unimplemented')}
        }
    };

    let localStore = {};

    const assignValue = async (data) => {
        var key = Object.keys(data)[0];
        localStore[key] = data[key];
    };

    const getValue = async (key) => {
        return localStore[key];
    };

    var expectedUserId = '1234';
    
    const setSpy = vi.spyOn(chrome.storage.local, 'set');
    setSpy.mockImplementation(async (kvp) => {
        await assignValue(kvp);
    });

    const getSpy = vi.spyOn(chrome.storage.local, 'get');
    getSpy.mockImplementation(async (key) => {
        return await getValue(key);
    });
  
    await setUserId(expectedUserId);
     

    var actualCorrelationId = await getUserId();
    expect(actualuserId).toBe(expectedUserId);
})}
```